# Problems with installing mail gem for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, failed-installation

I'm trying to install rails 3.0.7 on Mac OSX.  I'm using rvm and I've got ruby 1.9.2p180 installed.

When I run

```
gem install rails --version 3.0.7
```

It seems to work fine, until it gets to the mail gem.

```
Fetching: mail-2.2.17.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::DataError)
    invalid block type
```

The installer them stops and rails is not installed.  How do I get around this?

**Update:  Since I asked this question the mail gem has been updated to 2.2.19, and this seems to have solved the problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replicated your env (MacOS, ruby 1.9.2) and rails installed fine, along with the mail gem (2.2.17).

Perhaps try again? Maybe the package that was fetched was temporarily corrupt. You can also run gem with the verbose flag to see more info:

```
gem install rails -V --version 3.0.7
```

Comment: I actually tried installing it quite a few times... But I'm still getting that same error.  With the verbose flag on it just tells me 'Installing gem mail-2.2.17' and then I get the exact same error

Comment: Ok the mail gem has been updated to 2.2.19 which fixed the problem for me.